# How can we break down rows by some criteria?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, data-analysis

I have to write a query that displays the portfolio (current_due + past_due) and the number of unique customers as of the last date of each month for 2018, broken down by the period of delay (dpd): 0; 1-30; 31-60; 61-90; 91-180; 180+.

The tables are:

1. Contracts (id_contr, contact_name, id_client)
2. Clients (id_client, client_name)
3. Balance (date, id_contr, current_due, past_due, dpd)

I never faced a problem where I have to kind of sort data by some criteria in certain groups + making it for every last day of each month, so currently I'm stuck on solving that and really looking for any help possible.
Thank you!

Comment: Use `COUNT(DISTINCT id_client)` and `GROUP BY FLOOR(delay_period/30)`

Comment: I'll try that, thank you!